# Specify converter for Pandas index column in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to read in a CSV file with hexadecimal numbers in the index column:

```
InputBits, V0, V1, V2, V3
7A, 0.000594457716, 0.000620631282, 0.000569834178, 0.000625374384, 
7B, 0.000601155649, 0.000624282078, 0.000575955914, 0.000632111367, 
7C, 0.000606026872, 0.000629149805, 0.000582689823, 0.000634561234, 
7D, 0.000612115902, 0.000634625998, 0.000584526357, 0.000638235952, 
7E, 0.000615769413, 0.000637668328, 0.000590648093, 0.00064987256, 
7F, 0.000620640637, 0.000643144494, 0.000594933308, 0.000650485013,
```

I can do it using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=False,
                 converters={'InputBits': lambda x: int(x, 16)})
df.set_index('InputBits', inplace=True)
```

The problem is that this seems unnecessarily clunky. Is there a way to do something equivalent to the following?

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'InputBits': lambda x: int(x, 16)})
```

This fails because `InputBits` is now the first data column with

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ' 0.000594457716'
```

Comment: I think this has more to do with your csv file being in a non-standard format.  The standard format for a csv file would not have spaces after the commas (which is why your seeing a string with a space in front of it as your float value in your error message), and would not have trailing commas (pandas interprets this as a 6th column which is null. Since you only have 5 column headers, pandas assumes the first column is the index, which is why you need `index_col=False`).

Comment: Hmmm. You might be very right about that...

Comment: OK. You are completely correct.

Comment: Thanks. Answered my own question. I figure that as unlikely as it is, someone may run into this situation in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @root pointed out here, the issue in this example is the misalignment of the header with the column names and the column values, which all have a trailing comma. In fact, [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) deals with this specific scenario:

> If you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line, you might consider index_col=False to force pandas to *not* use the first column as the index (row names)

The solution here was first to run

```
sed -i 's/, \r$//' data.csv
```

to get rid of the final commas (and Windows line endings). Then, the expected command works almost out of the box:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='InputBits',
             converters={'InputBits': lambda x: int(x, 16)})
```