# Importing .csv with data type as float and index type as string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dtype

I'm importing data from several csv files using `pandas.read_csv()`. The number of rows/columns in each file is unknown. The data should be `float` (with `n.a.` replaced by `np.NaN`) but the index contains strings. See below an example of the data in the .csv file:

```
     X     Y     Z 
A   3.1   2.1   4.0
B   2.1   8.0   0.0
C   5.4   7.1   n.a.
D   7.6   5.0   5.5
```

I'm using the code below:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(file_name + '.csv', header=0, index_col=0, na_values=["n.a."], \
encoding="ISO-8859-1", thousands=",", dtype=float)
```

However, it returns the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'.
```

The reason for that is because the index contains strings. Is there a way to set dtype=float without converting the index itself?

As an alternative, I've tried reading the csv file as dtype=string and then converting each column using pandas.to_numeric(). However, since some of the .csv files contain thousands of columns and rows, this takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347377/specify-converter-for-pandas-index-column-in-read-csv
You could read the csv with converters then set the first column as index

Comment: You can try to set error_bad_lines=False, This will drop bad lines!

Answer (score 1):

You can import your data and add a index column with`.reset.index()` with floats. I hope this runs with you

Comment: I've tried doing that but unfortunately I still face the same issue since the column with strings becomes part of the dataframe